# XSLT the prefix xsl for element is not bound

Tags: xslt

I have an xml generated by a webservice based on openerp, it contains a prefix pp for many elements. I want to convert that xml file to another xml using xslt by selecting many elements.
When i try to execute the transformation, it shows me the error 'the prefix xsl for element is not bound' for the prefix pp.
I can't declare pp as it is described in many answers, how I can ignore the use of that prefix?

Comment: "I can't declare pp as it is described in many answers" - why not?  Mapping the URI to a suitable prefix within the stylesheet is the correct approach to this problem.

Comment: because I don't have an URI for that prefix, its generated automatically from openerp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.
we can use this XSLT transformation to ignore all the namespaces and prefix in our XML file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath provides the `pp:*` syntax to select all elements/attributes with a particular namespace URI regardless of their local names, but not (directly) to select all elements/attributes with a particular local name regardless of namespace.  If you don't know in advance what the namespace URI will be then instead of

```
pp:foo/pp:bar
```

you have to use tricks like

```
*[local-name() = 'foo']/*[local-name() = 'bar']
```

The fact that the document uses "pp" as the prefix is irrelevant, what matters to XPath and XSLT (and to any other namespace-aware XML processing tools) is the local name of an element and its namespace URI.  The prefix is simply a device to allow the parser to attach the correct namespace URI to each node.

Comment: Where I can write this line 
*[local-name() = 'foo']/*[local-name() = 'bar'] 
because I can't control how the XML file is generated, this XSLT is going to be used in ESB so it's going to be just a message and I will apply that XSLT on it.

Comment: @Rida you have to use this trick in all your `select` and `match` expressions that refer to the elements with a variable namespace. It's impossible to be any more specific without seeing an example of the XML and your current XSLT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I found a solution to my problem